# nginx / uwsgi-flask is changing port after form submission

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I set up a flask/uwsgi and a nginx container.

First of all, I could not access the site having nginx listen on port 80 and defining the docker port 80:80. No idea why this would not work.

So I made nginx listen on port 8090 and opening port 80:8090 in docker:

```
  nginx:
    container_name: fa_nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:8090
    networks:
      - fa_nginx_net
```

I am not exposing any ports in the dockerfile, there I copy just the conf file.

```
## nginx conf

server {
    listen 8090;
    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass web:8087;
}
```

Like that, I can access the site at `http://localhost` and browser around e.g. to `http://localhost/faq`.

However, when I submit a form (login), the nginx changes to another port and the redirected url looks like `http://localhost:8090/auth/login`.

the redirect in flask's login view after successful form validation is simply `return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))`.

Here is the flask/uwsgi setup (shortened version without all then env etc):

```
  web:
    container_name: fa_web
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8087"
    networks:
      - fa_nginx_net
```

```
[uwsgi]
plugin = python3

## python file where flask object app is defined.
wsgi-file = run.py

## The flask instance defined in run.py
callable = fapp
enable-threads = false
master = true
processes = 2
threads = 2

## socket on which uwsgi server should listen
protocol=http
socket = :8087
buffer-size=32768

## Gives permission to access the server.
chmod-socker = 660
vacuum = true

## various
die-on-term = true
```

```
## run.py
from app import create_app, db
import os

## init flask app
fapp = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'development':
        fapp.run(use_reloader=True, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8086)
    else:
        fapp.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8087)
```

I have no idea why this is happening and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it is working now...

Basically I removed `plugin=python3` and `protocol=http` from uwsgi.ini.

My setup looks now like this

```
## nginx default.conf
server {
    listen 8090;
    #server_name fa_web;
    ## To map the server block to an ip:
    #server_name  1.2.3.4;
    ## To map the server block to a domain:
    #server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass web:8087;
    }
}
```

```
## uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]

## python file where flask object app is defined.
wsgi-file = run.py

## The flask instance defined in myapp.py
callable = fapp
enable-threads = false
master = true
processes = 2
threads = 2

## socket on which uwsgi server should listen
socket = :8087
buffer-size=32768
#post-buffering=8192 ## workaround for consuming POST requests

## Gives permission to access the server.
chmod-socker = 660
vacuum = true

## various
die-on-term = true
```

The added headers in nginx conf didn't make a difference, just added them going forward configuring everything correctly.